# Is it possible to make a graphics object final for internal loop?

Tags: java, graphics, error-handling, timer, 2d

It seems like if my graphics object were final, as the error says it should be that I would never be able to change it. I have been reading about assigning variables to final variables before using them in my timer loop in order to get around this, but I don't even know how to begin to approach that for a graphics object. Would I need to copy the final graphics object back to the normal graphics object? Here is some code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test extends JPanel{

    abstract class graphic {
        public Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        public int[] location = new int[] {screenSize.width/2,screenSize.height/2};
    }

    public class gladiator extends graphic {

        void draw(Graphics g) {

        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillArc(location[0], location[1], 100, 100, 45, 90);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillArc((location[0]+50-10),(location[1]+50-10), 20, 20, 0, 360);

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        gladiator[] gladiator = new gladiator[2];
        ArrayList<gladiator> gladiatorList = new ArrayList<gladiator>();
    for (int a =0; a < 2; a++) {
    final gladiator[a] = new gladiator();
    final gladiatorList.add(gladiator[a]);      
    }

        new Timer(200, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int a = 0; a < gladiatorList.size(); a++) {
                gladiator[a].draw(g);
                }

            repaint();
            System.out.println("repainting");
        }
        }).start();

    }

    public void setLocation(int x, int y){
        //this.location[0] = x;
        //this.location[1] = y;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame jf=new JFrame();
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation
        (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setPreferredSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        jf.add(new Test());

        jf.pack();
        jf.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

This is the bit which returns that pretty much all of the line inside the for loop should be final.

```
        new Timer(200, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int a = 0; a < gladiatorList.size(); a++) {
                gladiator[a].draw(g);
                }

            repaint();
            System.out.println("repainting");
        }
        }).start();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just mark `gladiator` and `gladiatorList` as `final`.

Comment: Okay, I have done so to clarify things. The problem I was asking about is still present - it still wants graphics g to be final.

Comment: Then make it final too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really shouldn't have the timer in your `paintComponent`, it fires off a new timer whenever the OS feels like painting the component. You can see this by simply changing your repainting `sysout` to `System.out.println("repainting in: " + this);`

As for the finality of the `Graphics` variable:

```
final Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
```

Use `g2d` inside the timer.

Edit:
A full example:

```
public class ExampleAnimationOfMyStuff extends JPanel {

MovingRectangle[] rectangles = new MovingRectangle[20];

public ExampleAnimationOfMyStuff() {
    for (int i = 0; i < rectangles.length; i++) {
        rectangles[i] = new MovingRectangle();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Animated rectangles");
    ExampleAnimationOfMyStuff anime = new ExampleAnimationOfMyStuff();
    frame.getContentPane().add(anime);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    anime.animate();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
@Transient
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(1000, 1000);
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    for (MovingRectangle rectangle : rectangles) {
        g.setColor(rectangle.color);
        g.fillRect(rectangle.x, rectangle.y, rectangle.width,
                rectangle.height);
    }
}

public void animate() {
    new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for (MovingRectangle rectangle : rectangles) {
                rectangle.tick();
            }

            repaint();
            System.out.println("repainting");
        }
    }).start();
}



public static class MovingRectangle extends Rectangle {
    public static Random random = new Random();
    int speedX, speedY;
    Color color;

    public void tick() {
        if (getX() + speedX > 1000 || getX() + speedX < 0) {
            speedX *= -1;
        }

        if (getY() + speedY > 1000 || getY() + speedY < 0) {
            speedY *= -1;
        }

        setRect(getX() + speedX, getY() + speedY, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    public MovingRectangle() {
        super(random.nextInt(1000), random.nextInt(1000), random
                .nextInt(40), random.nextInt(40));

        this.speedX = (random.nextDouble() > 0.5) ? 4 : -4;
        this.speedY = (random.nextDouble() > 0.5) ? 4 : -4;
        this.color = new Color(random.nextInt(256), random.nextInt(256),
                random.nextInt(256));
    }
}

}
```

The above code seperates the timer from the paintcomponent using an array of custom objects (like you have), no need to declare things final and also removes the flickering you experienced (due to new timers firing off). It paints pretty rectangles on the screen that move about ;)

[image]

Comment: If not the paintComponent, where?

Also, when created g2d it stopped painting to the screen altogether. Do I need to redefine which graphics object I am displaying?

Comment: A method would be best. You can create the Test object and call .startAnimation(). Only one timer then.

Comment: So am I no longer overriding paintComponent? Note I went the other route and changed the argument to final Graphics g. It seemed simpler.

Comment: Also, this explains why it was flickering so much ;)

Comment: Yes it is better to do it that way, even better is to seperate them completely, see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

To use a local variable inside an anonymous class defined in the same method, you must make the local variable final.

This doesn't prevent you from modifying the object to which a reference variable points.

In your case, your anonymous class is using `g`, `gladiator` and `gladiatorList`. So mark all these final:

```
 protected void paintComponent( final Graphics g) {
    ...

    final gladiator[] gladiator = new gladiator[2];
    final ArrayList<gladiator> gladiatorList = new ArrayList<gladiator>();
```

Comment: Okay, I have done so to clarify things. The problem I was asking about is still present - it still wants graphics g to be final.

Comment: You have to mark that final too. Sorry, missed that at first. Fixed above.

Comment: I never declare graphics g so how can I change it to final? Also, won't this cause problems since I want to be updating graphics g?

Comment: Ah, I see below. Makes sense that it sets it in the data structure rather than setting the data itself.

Comment: You declare g as a formal parameter to your method paintComponent(). The final modifier just marks the reference non-modifiable - you can't change it to null or to point to a different object. But you can still call any method on the object itself.

Comment: When I try to declare graphics g in my paintComponent() method it says it was already defined. Should I change the variable of graphics and refer to that other name instead? When I do that I have problems with it not being initialized when I call the draw method.

Comment: You already have g declared. Just add the modifier "final" before it, as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

If you make your variable `final`, it means that that variable will always be a reference to the same object instance. It does not mean that the contents of the object instance cannot be changed. You cannot assign a new reference to that variable, but you can do anything you want to the instance itself (call methods that might modify its state, read/write the fields, etc.).